# Java- About strings

Tags: java, string

I am doing some validation using simple Java, I am coding as below

```
if (something.equals("ABC"))

      expectedvalue = "TEST1";

else if(something.equals("DEF"))

      expectedvalue = "TEST5";

// and so on....
```

My issue here is that, if `something.equals("ABC")`, `expectedvalue` can be any of these two values -> `"TEST1"` or  `"TEST2"`

During validation, in the output, I do not get error if I give `"TEST1"` for `expectedvalue`. It should do the same even if I give `"TEST2"`. How to do that?

Comment: Can you elaborate what do you mean? You should return a random expected value between 1 and 2?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: About 90% of programming is knowing how to recognize what the question is and describe it clearly.

Comment: Right now your code is saying if 'something' is 'ABC' then set 'expectedValue' to 'TEST1'...what you are asking doesn't match your code

Comment: You are right, right now it says so, but i would like to code so that-> if 'something' is 'ABC' then set 'expectedValue' to 'TEST1' or 'TEST2'

Comment: @djangofan How is this in any way a duplicate of that?

Comment: Can someone throw some light on this?

Answer (score 2):

You have to have a Set of allowed values.

```
Set<String> allowed = new HashSet<String>();
allowed.put("TEST1");
allowed.put("TEST2");

//and then you can use this set
if (allowed.contains(yourValueToCheck)) {
    // do what you need
```

Also note that it is safer to compare strings like this:

```
if ("ABC".equals(something)) // to protect yourself from NullPointerExceptions
```

Comment: I tend to stay away from yoda conditions with strings. If my string is null, I want to know about it!

Comment: you will know about it by your app being crashed. The other way to know about it is just check if it is null or not and handle error case yourself without breaking the app

Comment: A NullPointerException is almost always a sign that something has gone wrong earlier in the program, and that we're no longer in a reliable state.  Allowing the exception to be thrown and crash the application earlier gives us the opportunity to fix the real bug.  Attempting to hobble along when the application has already failed just gives us the chance to compound the damage.

Comment: In many cases I've worked with NULL was a legal value (meaning attribute or some flag wasn't set)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could change your test to test with an OR statment?

```
if(expectedvalue.equals("TEST1") || expectedvalue.equals("TEST2"))
     .....
```

Comment: If should not error if the expectedvalue is either of TEST1, TEST2...not a comparision

Comment: That's what this does - In English, it says "If the expectedvalue is TEST1, or if the expectedvalue is TEST2, then do this"

Comment: but i would like to code so that-> if 'something' is 'ABC' then set 'expectedValue' to 'TEST1' or 'TEST2'